# How can I send received packet using raw sockets in C?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I've wrote some code, which is not working. I need to send incoming packets to another host(2.2.2.1). This code receiving packet but can't send it. What I'm doing wrong?
I'm receiving packet, than copy packet to another array and than trying to send it using sendto() function.

```
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <netinet/ip.h> 
#include <netinet/tcp.h>   

#define PCKT_LEN 8192

int main(){
    int s, s1;
    char buffer[PCKT_LEN];
    struct sockaddr saddr;
    struct sockaddr_in daddr;
    memset(buffer, 0, PCKT_LEN);

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(s < 0){
        printf("socket() error");
        return -1;
    }
    int one = 1;
    const int *val = &one;
    if(setsockopt (s, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, val, sizeof(one))<0){
        printf("setsock");
        return -1;
    }
    s1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(s1 < 0){
        printf("sock2 error");
        return -1;
    }
    if(setsockopt (s1, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, val, sizeof(one)) < 0){
        printf("setsock");
        return -1;
    }
    int saddr_size = sizeof(saddr);
    int daddr_size = sizeof(daddr); 
    int header_size = sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct tcphdr);
    unsigned int count;

    daddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    daddr.sin_port = htons(1234);
    daddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr ("2.2.2.1");

    char *datagram, *data;
    datagram = (char*)calloc(4096, sizeof(char));
    struct iphdr *iph;
    struct tcphdr *tcph;
    int counter = 0;
    while(counter != 3){
        counter++;
        if(recvfrom(s, buffer, PCKT_LEN , 0, &saddr, &saddr_size) < 0){
            printf("recvfrom() error");
            return -1;
        }
        else{
            int i = header_size;
            int packet_len = ntohs(iph->tot_len);           
            memset(datagram, 0 ,4096);
            iph = (struct iphdr*) buffer;
            tcph = (struct tcphdr*) (buffer + sizeof(struct ip));
            data = buffer + sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct tcphdr);

            i = 0;
            for(; i < packet_len-sizeof(struct iphdr)-sizeof(struct tcphdr); i++)
                printf("%c", data[i]);
                 printf("\n");

            memcpy(datagram, iph, sizeof(struct iphdr));
            memcpy(datagram+sizeof(struct iphdr), tcph , sizeof(struct tcphdr));
            memcpy(datagram+sizeof(struct iphdr)+sizeof(struct tcphdr), data,packet_len-sizeof(struct iphdr)-sizeof(struct tcphdr));

            iph->daddr = daddr.sin_addr.s_addr;

            if (sendto (s, datagram, packet_len, 0, &daddr, &daddr_size) < 0){
                printf("sendto() error");
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
    close(s);
    close(s1);
    free(datagram);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where are the headers? please post them too.

Comment: Did you include `stdlib.h` and `unistd.h`? and please delete the previous comment.

Comment: No,I didn't include stdlib.h, but I included unistd.h. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You didn't include `stdlib.h` and hence `calloc()` is implicitly declared so the compiler assumes it returns `int`, and that will cause many problems.

   Also, don't use `calloc()` unless you really want to initialize data to `0`'s, because if you have a problem with data initialization, then nothing bad will happen, and you will never know. Use `malloc()` unless you are going to `memset(pointer, 0, size);` later, which isn't bad either, in my case, I always use `malloc()`.
2. You didn't include `unistd.h` either so you have a missing declaration for `close()` too. This one is not causing problems, but just because conicidentially it returns `int`.
3. Your `sendto()` call is also wrong, the last argument should be of type `socklen_t` and you passed a `int *`, so fix it like this

   ```
   sendto (s, datagram, packet_len, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&daddr, daddr_size) < 0
   /*                                                            ^ no & here */
   ```
4. To avoid some of the warnings that will appear when you ask the compiler to warn you you will need  to declare these to variables as `socklen_t`

   ```
   socklen_t saddr_size = sizeof(saddr);
   socklen_t daddr_size = sizeof(daddr);
   ```

   and also you need the cast that you see above `(struct sockaddr *)&daddr`.
5. The most important problem is that you try to access `iph` without initializing it

   ```
   size_t packet_len = ntohs(iph->tot_len);
   ```

   this should go after `iph = (struct iphdr *)buffer;`.

   The cause for this, is precisely that your code is so messy that it's hard to notice that.

You can avoid all this by using compiler warnings, like this

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror sourcefile.c -o executable
```

**Note**: organize your code better, it's very hard to follow, and that's not good if someone else has to review it, like I did just now, also for you it's not good, because when you look at it months from now, you will be very angry at the person who wrote that mess.

Comment: I did everything you said, but I haven't got any output - printf isn't working. But in wireshark I see just incoming packets.

Comment: @user3425448 I've updated the answer, it turns out there is another more important issue with your code.